# Set width of div as width of parent of parent

Tags: html, css

```
<div class = "x" style="width:100%;">
    <div class = "y" style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <div class = "z" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "yy" style="width:50%;float:right;">
        <div class = "zz" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can the width of div of class "z"/"zz" be set to that of div of class "x" through css alone?

**UPDATE**
The solution is here [link](http://codepen.io/rnjailamba/pen/Wrpejz)(using the answer given below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to set the parent x to a relative position and the z div to an absolute position

```
.x{
position: relative;
}
.z{
position: absolute ;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inherit` property. The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "x">
   <div class = "y">
       <div class = "z">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.x
{
width:100px; 
border:1px solid red;
height:100px;
}

.z{
width:inherit; 
border:1px solid green;
height:100px;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddm95mjb/) for the same.

Comment: If the width of y is also set then this doesnt work - https://jsfiddle.net/1L53mq5L/

Comment: Yes, the inherit keyword limits the inheritance of a child element's property from a parent element. It was not mentioned in your question earlier that `y` may have a width. Thats why I provided this solution.

Answer (score 1):

give .x width , then give .z  width:inherit; 
Otherwise,
I think you have to set them one by one unless you are going to make box model, make .x be the big box,then put .y and .z in box.

give the .x a width for example is 100%, then give .y as 25px. You may going to use {display:-webkit-box;} and {-webkit-box-flex:1;}attributes.then you can give x .x a max-width number and y 0r z width, the one left will flexible depend on how big your screen is at times.

but as your html you probably have to give the width separately,unless you use box model.

hope this will help you little bit.